# Solaris and internal-sftp

Tags: ssh, solaris, sftp

Does sunSSH internal-sftp support `-d` option as does the equivalent in openSSH?

Basically in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file I do:

```
Match Group sftp
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /foo
  AllowTcpForwarding no
```

The above is possible on Linux, but I cannot find any documentation wrt Solaris and internal-sftp.

The reason why I assume it doesn't work is because SFTP sessions cannot login with the above config. If I remove the parameters following `internal-sftp` it works.

Solaris version is 11.3. (latest and greatest)

Comment: Also, what does the output from `man sshd_config` tell you?

Comment: @AndrewHenle manual page for sshd_config does not talk about any configuration options for `sftp-server`.

Comment: Did you try [looking in the `Subsystem` section?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54775/sshd-config-4.html#scrolltoc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it does not work, it is most probably not supported. You can simply find out from the manual page for `sftp-server`.

As a workaround, you can use a script that would do the `cd` and then start the `sftp-server` from the default location (needs to be copied into the `chroot`).

Comment: Good point. On Linux (i.e with openSSH), the options that are accepted by `internal-sftp` are the same as those accepted by  `sftp-server`. So therefore the man page for sftp-server can be used. But I wouldn't know if this applies to sunSSH as well. Probably, I guess. (in which case we can conclude that `-d` is **not** a possible option for `internal-sftp`).

Comment: Why they would be different? It is the same code that is run by `sftp-server` and the `internal-sftp` (unless you installed the first from other source).

Comment: Yes, I just wasn't aware of that. :-)   I have accepted your answer because it is the one which most precisely answers my immediate question (is `-d` option supported or not?). Thanks. However, as for the workaround I'll most likely not use what you suggest but rather switch to openSSH instead as per sleepweasel's answer.

Comment: Yes, switching to OpenSSH is a good idea unless you need something very special from sunssh.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using v11.3, you could also switch from using SunSSH to OpenSSH if you wanted.

Here's a proc taken from the Solaris 11 cheatsheet put together by Joerg:

> Since Solaris 11.3 it’s possible to use OpenSSH instead of SunSSH.

```
pkg install openssh

pkg mediator -a ssh

pkg set-mediator -I openssh ssh
```

Comment: Sure, this is a possible option for me. By the way: The official documentation for the Solaris 11.3 SSH implementation - including information about how to switch between sunSSH and openSSH - is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54793/index.html).